# Coupling of LC circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, harmonic-oscillator, models

I am reading an old article in a physics journal in which the author explains that the frequency between two identical, but capacitively coupled oscillators becomes $\omega_\pm=\omega_0\sqrt{1\pm\kappa}$ with $\kappa=Ad/(4\pi R^3)$:

[image]

[image]

I do not understand how the expression for $\kappa$ is derived. Also, is it important for the derivation that the LC circuits are capacitively coupled? Would the whole reasoning of the article, namely that two LC circuits can be used to explain van der Waals interaction, break down if the LC circuits were inductively coupled?

Comment: I do not know how the $4 \pi$ gets in the denominator but the energy in the capacitor is proportional to its volume and the energy coupled between the capacitors is inversely proportional to the "volume between them", whatever that is, and that is why the cube of their mutual distance shows up.

Comment: Which article ?